# WSO2 Identiy server 5.1.0 For what is shindig.war needed?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Just wondering for what the shindig.war is good for? Is it only needed when the dashboard is used?

Can it safely removed if the dashboard is not used?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Its used by the Dashboards.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Shindig is used to render gadgets in the WSO2 Identity Server dashboard (https://localhost:9443/dashboard).

Even though the dashboard is not used, WSO2 does not recommend removing shindig.war as it is shipped with the default pack (This scenario should be thoroughly tested before deploying into a production environment).

Comment: Thanks for the information. But if it is not recommended to remove the war file, what is the recommendation to disable the login page and the test users which the shindig application offers.  This unnecessary login page may be a concern for security reviews.

Comment: @Hos Without removing the WAR you can restrict the access from the Load Balancer.